# Ambiguous Call of "long unsigned int" for "uint32_t"

Tags: c++

I have a bunch of functions overloaded for all of the `[u]int{8|16|32|64}_t` types:

```
std::string f( uint8_t) { /*something*/ }
std::string f(  int8_t) { /*something*/ }
std::string f(uint16_t) { /*something*/ }
std::string f( int16_t) { /*something*/ }
std::string f(uint32_t) { /*something*/ }
std::string f( int32_t) { /*something*/ }
std::string f(uint64_t) { /*something*/ }
std::string f( int64_t) { /*something*/ }
//A few more overloads with a few more types (bool, float, const char*, etc.)
```

I now call the function name with an argument of type `long unsigned int`:

```
template <typename type_blah> class Something { public:
        //...
        std::string call_f(void) const {
            return f(*((type_blah*)(internal_variable)));
        }
        //...
};
```

This produces an error:

> error: call of overloaded 'f(long unsigned int&)' is ambiguous

---

This happens, I suppose, because `unsigned int` and `uint32_t` are different types.  But, I can't overload the function more for `long unsigned int` because this is a redundant definition.  I.e.:

```
std::string f(long unsigned int) { /*something*/ }
```

. . . produces:

> error: 'std::string f(uint32_t)' previously defined here

---

It seems the type mechanisms are working against each other: it can't figure out which conversion to use because each conversion is equally valid, but a no-conversion overload can't be defined because it already has been.

I can't cast the argument for various reasons.  Is there a way out of this?

Platform is g++ MinGW x86 running on Windows 7 x86-64.

Comment: Can you please make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to show us? Or at least the function declarations and how you call it?

Comment: Are you using a compiler that has "long" as 32 bits?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I'm not sure that could explain it.  Assuming the OP has created the overloads as he claims, then `f(some_unsigned_long)` should exactly match at most one of the overloads.

Comment: Added some simplified code.  The compiler is using `-m32` with the listed platform.  If that doesn't give enough info. on the types' sizes, I can run a test with sizeof to determine them.

Comment: `This happens, I suppose, because unsigned int and uint32_t are different types.` Or, rather, because they're _not_. (see 18.4.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is my "test" based on the code provided above:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

std::string f( uint8_t) { return "ui8";}
std::string f(  int8_t) { return "i8";}
std::string f(uint16_t) { return "ui16";}
std::string f( int16_t) { return "i16";}
std::string f(uint32_t) { return "ui32";}
std::string f(unsigned long long int) { return "unsigned long long";}
std::string f(unsigned long int) { return "unsigned long";}
std::string f( int32_t) { return "i32";}
//std::string f(uint64_t) { return "ui64";}
std::string f( int64_t) { return "i64";}

int main()
{
    unsigned long x = 42;
    unsigned y = 17;
    uint32_t z = 9;
    uint64_t w = 135;
    std::cout << "x: "<< f(x) << " y: " << f(y) << " z: " << f(z) << " w: " << f(w) << std::endl;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ clang++ ambig.cpp -std=c++0x -Wall -m64
$ ./a.out 
x: unsigned long y: ui32 z: ui32 w: unsigned long
$ clang++ ambig.cpp -std=c++0x -Wall -m32
$ ./a.out 
x: unsigned long y: ui32 z: ui32 w: unsigned long long
```

(I copied my run with clang++, but the results are the same for g++)

This makes sure that both the `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long` types are covered. Unfortunately, one of those is `uint64_t`, so it has to be removed.

If you do declare variables as `unsigned long`, you must supply a function that takes exactly that - and relying on it being equivalent to `uint32_t` is probably incorrect - even if they are the same bitsize.

Comment: "Unfortunately, one of those is `uint64_t`, so it has to be removed." Exactly; but I don't know in advance which it will be.  However, I think this gives the necessary clue: I'll just have to deal with using one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

What platform are you using?

On Windows (Visual Studio 2010), `unsigned long int` is a distinct type from the others you mentioned.

Adding an overload specifically for that type resolved the error.  This answer (and/or Google) may shed more light on the issue: [Type of unsigned long is different from uint32_t and uint64_t on Windows (VS2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611467).

I defined an overload for `unsigned long int` like so:

```
std::string f( unsigned long int val )
{
  // Check that we chose the correct corresponding type
  // (This may vary by platform!)
  assert( sizeof( unsigned long int ) == sizeof( uint32_t ) );

  return f( static_cast<uint32_t>( val ) );
}
```

...tested in Visual Studio 2010 like so:

```
void main()
{
  std::cout << "sizeof( unsigned long int ): " << sizeof( unsigned long int ) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sizeof( uint32_t ): "          << sizeof( uint32_t )          << std::endl;

  unsigned long int x = 1u;
  std::cout << f( x ) << std::endl;
}
```

...and got the expected result:

```
sizeof( unsigned long int ): 4
sizeof( uint32_t ): 4
uint32_t
```

Comment: added platform and some code in edit.  I had seen that link; it didn't really offer a *solution* though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're defining overloads for (nearly?) every type, perhaps your function should be a template instead?

```
template < typename T >
std::string f( T )
{
  /*something*/
}
```

If there is one set of code that works for all - or even most - types, that would save you a lot of work as well.

If for some reason you still need to force the call with the `unsigned long int` value to treat it as some other type (like `uint32_t`), you could specify the template instantiation at the call-site:

```
return f<uint32_t>( *internal_variable );
```

Comment: It was originally a template, but needs to be an overload instead since some types that one might think are valid, aren't.  As above, I cannot call a specific instantiation anyway.